# Why is my (try-catch) code executed too soon in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, console.log, winston

On the response of an `HTTP GET` call (with native http module), I try to`JSON.parse()` the response after the  `end` event is emitted. I know for sure the the data i'm getting is valid JSON but still the `JSON.parse` throw an error. And my logs indicate that the `JSON.parse` is invoked before it should.

```
res.on("end", () => {
  console.log('Req ended message is', body);

  try {
    var passport = JSON.parse(body);
  } catch (e) {
    w.info(
     "Cannot parse the response from : " +
     process.env.mongo_api_host +
     " | error  : " +
     e
   );
  }
  callback(passport);
 return;
});
```

And my log shows :

```
info: Getting MongoDB passport for model : CESI
info: Cannot parse the response from : mongo_api | error  : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
info: Req ended message is *long valid JSON data*
```

We can clearly see in the logs that the parse error is caught and logged before the `"Req ended message is : ... stuff"`.

What am I missing ?

Edit 1 :

Even by putting `callback(passport)` inside try block as suggested in comment it still does it :

```
      res.on("end", () => {
        try {
          console.log("Req ended message is", body);
          var passport = JSON.parse(body);
          //TODO What if you get an array ?
          if (passport._id) delete passport._id;
          callback(passport);
        } catch (e) {
          w.info(
            "Cannot parse the response from : " +
              process.env.mongo_api_host +
              " | error  : " +
              e
          );
        }
        return;
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: move `callback(passport)` inside the try block.

Comment: What is `w.info`? Does it log to a different stream than `console.log`? Is it buffered maybe? Try to replace it by `console.info`.

Comment: It's Winston with default configuration :).

Comment: The message ordering is probably due to buffering in `console`, as @Bergi said.  You can avoid that by writing both messages through the same mechanism, either `console.log` or `w.info`.  For the JSON problem, try taking the JSON string from the `'... message is', body` output and write a small standalone program that tries to `JSON.parse` that string.  If it fails, you can successively pare down the string and re-run the program until you find the problem.